# gmail does not receive mail from php send_mail

Tags: php, email, gmail, send

I have a register / login system where an email is sent to the registered email address with an activation code. Outlook.com receives the mail and so on, but for some reason Gmail does not receive the mail. I do not know why. If anyone can help me.

thanks in advance

```
<?php

function send_mail($subject, $to, $text) {

$message = '

<html><body bgcolor="#f0f0f0">

<table width="720" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

<tr>

<td><font style="font-family:Segoe UI, Arial; color:#0a0a0a;"><h1>Happitual</h1></font></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<font style="font-family:Segoe UI, Arial; color:#0a0a0a;">

<p>' . $text . '</p>

</font>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<font style="font-family:Segoe UI, Arial; color:#0a0a0a; font-size:12px;">

&copy All Rights Reserved. Happitual.

</font>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</body></html>

';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: Happitual <welcome@happitual.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

?>
```

Comment: You sure it doesn't go to spam folder?

Comment: Might be improper use of, or lack of [**mail( ) headers**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Could be a number of things. Got some code to show us? Hard to tell without it.

Comment: A few more reasons could be omitted `Reply-to`, and/or `From` etc. Again, I'm not a very good **"Shot" in dark**, *"as it were"*.

Comment: I posted a code sample

Comment: Where is the function call to `send_mail()`?

Comment: i ran this locally and it got to my gmail and several other accounts, you are calling send_mail() ??

Comment: It's on a different PHP file, where I include this PHP.

Comment: Where are you pre-defined variables? This is NOT full code. I'm backing away on this one, good luck; *I wish you well.*

Comment: And for some reason it does not work for me

Comment: For "some" reason? I don't know the "reason", because I don't see "full" code. As I said earlier, I'm backing away on this one. You never posted any code in your previous questions, so how do you expect people to help you? My best advice to you Liam; get on Google, find yourself a dozen or so PHP forms, test them out and see which ones that don't come up as Spam and work with it. Or, get yourself a copy of PHPMailer or other equivalent, and you'll be up and running in no time. What with the time you wasted asking to fix it, you could have spent the same amount of time with a working script.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help you out. But can you please provide a copy of your code? you might not be using the right syntax or maybe the mail() function is set the wrong way. Have you checked your headers? how about your MIME version? Please paste your code when you can.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Dagon Since Diego cannot comment due to insufficient rep points, and the fact that the OP did not post any code and leaving us all "in the dark", this so far is the best answer, given the circumstances. It's noble and commendable. P.s.: Given the OP's track record of not showing code for all questions that were asked, is not fair to Diego of having been downvoted, by whoever it was that downvoted his answer. *Just saying*.